# How to improve this javascript elevator / parallax / pin-it element function

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

I was researching through the world wide web for a javascript function  ”pin parallax scroll event” or whatever you’d like to call it.

[Scrollmagic](http://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/simple_pinning.html) has a solution of this, but it has a set value. Many times you wont know the actual height of the content.

Couldn't find a solution that was fitting my needs so I built my own in jQuery.

Althought my solution isn't perfect. When the scroll-event is fired, it feels laggy and you can see the elevator-element being moved for a tiny moment (during like 200ms).

Anyone has a clue how to improve this?

```
      $(window).scroll(function (){

        var currentPos = $(document).scrollTop(); // Our current position

        console.log(currentPos); //So we can se our current position in the console

        var targetElemTopPos = $("#elevator .right").offset().top; //Value of our targets top position
        var targetElemenBotPos = $("#elevator .right").outerHeight(); //Total of our targets height
        var targetLeftBosPos = $("#elevator .left").outerHeight(); //Total value of our elevator

        var amountOfTop = targetElemenBotPos - targetLeftBosPos; //Calc the difference from sections top to elevators top

        //The elevator algorithm
        if ( (currentPos > targetElemTopPos) && (currentPos < targetElemenBotPos) ) {
            //If the current position is greater than targets top position
            //AND if the current position is less than targets bottom position
            //Start the elevator
            console.log('Elevator in movement');
            $('#elevator .left').addClass('fixed');
            $( '#elevator .left' ).css( 'top', 0 );
        } else if (currentPos > targetElemTopPos) {
            //Howeaver if the current position is greater than targets bottom position
            // Stop the elevator and push it down so we can take the elevator up later if we want to
            console.log('Elevator has reached the destination');
            $('#elevator .left').removeClass('fixed');
            $( '#elevator .left' ).css( 'top', amountOfTop );
        } else {
            //Else just let the elevator wait on a passanger
            console.log('Elevator on standby');
            $('#elevator .left').removeClass('fixed');
            $( '#elevator .left' ).css( 'top', 0 );
        }
      });
```

https://codepen.io/jeffdesign/pen/jBOdgE

(The lagg is more obvious in full-screen and in Safari)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not into JQuery but you could try this vanilla code:
It alsow handles the case when the content height of the sticky element is bigger than the screen and only uses one scroll listener for multiple instances.

```js
(function(global, document, undefined) {
  'use strict';
  const SCROLL_DIRECTION = {
    UP: -1,
    DOWN: 1
  };
  var ticking = false;
  var currentScrollPosition = 0;
  var lastScrollPosition = 0;
  var scrollDirection = 1;
  var stickies = [];
  
  function StickyScroll(selector, options) {
    var self = this;
    var target = null;
    var parent = null;

    options = options || {};
    options = Object.assign({}, self.defaults, options);
 
    target = document.querySelector(selector);
    if(!target) return;
    self.targetSnapshot = target.getBoundingClientRect();
    parent = target.parentNode;
    
    if(options.boundTo) {
      parent = document.querySelector(options.boundTo);
    }

    self.uid = StickyScroll.UID++;
    
    self.target = target;
    self.parent = parent;
    self.options = options;
    stickies[self.uid] = self;
  }
  
  StickyScroll.UID = 0;
  StickyScroll.prototype.defaults = {
    boundTo: null,
    directionOffset: 50
  }
  StickyScroll.prototype.update = function() {
      var targetRect = this.target.getBoundingClientRect();
      var parentRect = this.parent.getBoundingClientRect();
      var targetHeight = targetRect.height;
      var targetBottom = currentScrollPosition + targetHeight;
      var parentHeight = parentRect.height;
      var parentTop = this.parent.offsetTop;
      
      if(currentScrollPosition > lastScrollPosition + this.options.directionOffset) {
        scrollDirection = SCROLL_DIRECTION.DOWN;
        lastScrollPosition = currentScrollPosition;
      } else if(currentScrollPosition < lastScrollPosition - this.options.directionOffset) {
        scrollDirection = SCROLL_DIRECTION.UP;
        lastScrollPosition = currentScrollPosition;
      }
      if(currentScrollPosition > parentTop && targetBottom < parentHeight + parentTop) {
        this.target.style.height = targetHeight + 'px';
        this.target.style.position = 'fixed';

        if(scrollDirection === SCROLL_DIRECTION.DOWN) {
          this.target.style.top = 0 + 'px';
          this.target.style.bottom = null;
        }
        else {
          this.target.style.top = null;
          this.target.style.bottom = 0 + 'px';
        }
      } else if(targetBottom >= parentHeight + parentTop) {
        this.target.style.position = 'absolute';
        this.target.style.top = null;
        this.target.style.bottom = 0;
        this.parent.style.position = 'relative';
      } else {
        this.parent.style.position = null;
        this.target.style.position = null;
        this.target.style.top = null;
        this.target.style.bottom = null;
      }
      
      ticking = false;
  }
 
  global.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
    stickies.forEach(function(sticky) {
      if (!ticking) {
        currentScrollPosition = document.body.scrollTop;
        window.requestAnimationFrame(sticky.update.bind(sticky));
        ticking = true;
      }
    });
  });
  
  global.StickyScroll = StickyScroll;
  
})(window, document)

let x = new StickyScroll('#elevator .left'); // init
let y = new StickyScroll('#dd'); // should not init
```

```css
 body, html, h1, h2, h3, p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
header {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}
header h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#elevator {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#elevator .left {
  background-color: #e67e22;
  width: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  height: 150vh;
}
#elevator .left h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#elevator .right {
  background-color: #34495e;
  width: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  float: right;
  line-height: 2em;
}
#elevator .right p {
  padding: 2em;
}
footer {
  min-height: 1200px;
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2em;
}
footer h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 250px 0;
  font-size: 4em;
}
footer p {
  line-height: 2em;
  color: #fff;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <header class="100vh">
      <h1>I am a header</h1>
    </header>

    <section id="elevator">
      <div class="left 100vh">
        <h2>I am Mr. Elevator</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <p>Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
        <p>Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec sed odio dui. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.</p>
        <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.</p>
        <p>Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.</p>
        <p>Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
        <p>Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec sed odio dui. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.</p>
        <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.</p>
        <p>Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.</p>
        <p>Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
        <p>Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec sed odio dui. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.</p>
        <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.</p>
        <p>Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.</p>
        <p>Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
        <p>Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec sed odio dui. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.</p>
        <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.</p>
        <p>Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.</p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <footer>
      <h1>I am bigfooter</h1>
      <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</p>
      <p>Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
      <p>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
      <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</p>
      <p>Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
      <p>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

When you do use "greater than" and "less than" in if/ifelse/else the condition wont be true when the value equals the current value. So the solution was quite easy.

All I did was edit from:

```
if ( (currentPos > targetElemTopPos) && (currentPos < targetElemenBotPos) )
```

To:

```
if ( (currentPos >= targetElemTopPos) && (currentPos <= targetElemenBotPos) )
```

And same on the rest of the function.